# What is the disadvantages of Java Bean Class?

Tags: java

I read these 2 statement mentioned below from the book **Effective Java**

**1st**

> Unfortunately, the JavaBeans pattern has serious disadvantages of its
>   own. Because construction is split across multiple calls, a JavaBean
>   may be in an inconsistent state partway through its construction.The
>   class does not have the option of enforcing consistency merely by
>   checking the validity of the constructor parameters. Attempting to use
>   an object when it’s in an inconsistent state may cause failures that
>   are far removed from the code containing the bug, hence difficult to
>   debug.

**2nd**

> A related disadvantage is that the JavaBeans pattern precludes the
>   possibility of making a class immutable (Item 15), and requires added
>   effort on the part of the programmer to ensure thread safety. It is
>   possible to reduce these disadvantages by manually “freezing” the
>   object when its construction is complete and not allowing it to be
>   used until frozen, but this variant is unwieldy and rarely used in
>   practice. Moreover, it can cause errors at runtime, as the compiler
>   cannot ensure that the programmer calls the freeze method on an object
>   before using it.

,and I am not able to understand what exactly these 2 statement wants to convey , Can you guys help me out to understand the above statement .

**Update**

I have read answers(not all) on this post , most of community members suggested me to use `Constructor Pattern` but in the same book these lines have said

> Static factories and constructors share a limitation: they do not
>   scale well to large numbers of optional parameters. Consider the case
>   of a class representing the Nutrition Facts label that appears on
>   packaged foods. These labels have a few required fields—serving size,
>   servings per container, and calories per serving— and over twenty
>   optional fields—total fat, saturated fat, trans fat, cholesterol,
>   sodium, and so on. Most products have nonzero values for only a few of
>   these optional fields.

For this Scenario we use [telescoping constructor](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/05/telescoping-constructor-antipattern.html) pattern but

> The telescoping constructor pattern works, but it is hard to write
>   client code when there are many parameters, and harder still to read
>   it.The reader is left wondering what all those values mean and must
>   carefully count parameters to find out. Long sequences of identically
>   typed parameters can cause subtle bugs. If the client accidentally
>   reverses two such parameters, the compiler won’t complain, but the
>   program will misbehave at runtime

that is why suugested to use `JavaBeans` over `constructor pattern`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's see the simplest Java Bean:

```
class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {this.firstName = firstName;}
   public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {this.lastName = lastName;}
}
```

The following code creates instance of `Person` an initiates it:

```
Person president = new Person();
p.setFirstName("George");
p.setLastName("Bush");
```

As you can see:

1. Initialization is indeed split across 3 lines. This means that the object is in constant state when all 3 lines are completed and in not consistent state before that.

   2. The object is indeed mutable: values that it calls may be changed by invoking of setter.

Why is this bad? Because our class `Person` is not thread-safe and therefore we cannot use it directly in multi threaded environment without thinking about syncrhonization.

Here is an example. Several years ago Barak Obama became the President of the US. How can we express this in code?

```
p.setFirstName("Barak");
p.setLastName("Obama");
```

In mutlti threaded envronent the `president` object is in wrong state when when `setFristName()` had already completed and `setLastName()` has not called yet because the object contains "Barak Bush" that is obviously wrong.

What is the solution? Let's make `Person immutable:

```
class Person {
   private final String firstName;
   private final String lastName;
   Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
   public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
}
```

As you can see there is not way to change either first or last name stored in object. The fields a `final` and do not have setters. So, our example looks like:

Person president = new Person("George", "Bush");
// elections.....
president = new Person("Barak", "Obama");

Since `Person` is immutable we cannot re-use the old instanceo of `Person` and change its attribute. We have to create the new instance instead. If `president` is `volatitle` reference assignment is atomic and therefore the code is thread safe.

*Update*

The problem of constructors is that they are not flexible. Our example has only 2 parameters. But think about real world when class `Person` has probably 20 or more field. In this case creating of such object is pretty verbose.

Moreover some fields can be optional. In this case you will probably want to create several overloaded constructors with different number of parameters. To avoid dupplicate assignemnt code it is common technique to use so called telescopic constructors, i.e. pattern when constructor invokes other constructor. This pattern is good but in some too verbose and hard for modifications.

This just means that there is not ideal solution. Each solution has its own advantages and disadvantages.

BTW the solution that combines advantages of immutable object and flexibility of object creation and initialization is builder pattern.

I will not write all examples that are needed for better understanding of these issues. But I hope that my answer helped you a little bit. Now you have a starting point and can learn this issue using other resources. Good luck.

Comment: Actually reference assignment is always atomic in Java. `volatile` only ensure that the reference is not cached ...

Comment: @Guillaume, you are right. I just did not want to overload my explanation.

Comment: I got your point , but can you enlighten  on  updated part of question , So that i can mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @AlexR I just want to ask that if a class has multiple data members , Some of them are mandatory but others are not , So at this point if we use constructor like this `new Test(1,2,"Important-Item",null,null)` ,**here null is non mandatory field**  but creating object like this for a long chain of data members will easily make users to mix the parameters position , then in that case is using the constructor is good or not ?

Comment: @NeerajJain, you got the point. This is the disadvantage of this technique.  However `Builder` pattern that I mentioned in the end of my answer helps to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes I got it and that is why this answer is accepted , yes the next topic in that book is same builder pattern as you mentioned , I'll explore the rest from it ,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a `Person` bean, which has a `firstname` and a `lastname` properties:

```
class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    public String getFirstname() { return firstname; }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) { this.firstname = firstname; }
    public String getLastname() { return lastname; }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) { this.lastname = lastname; }
}
```

For that class to be fully initialized, we need to set both the firstname and the last name. But in this implementation, nothing prevent us from doing something like:

```
Person paulSmith = new Person();
paul.setFirstname("Paul");
paul.getLastname(); // will not throw an error, but is functionnaly invalid
paul.setLastname("Smith");
```

In comparison, if you implement this class as:

```
class Person {
    private final String firstname;
    private final String lastname;
    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getFirstname() { return firstname; }
    public String getLastname() { return lastname; }
}
```

you ensure than immediately after construction, the class is fully initialized:

```
Person paulSmith = new Person("Paul", "Smith");
// impossible to call getLastname() before lastname is initialized
```

I also made that class immutable at the same time: Paul can never change his name. That might or might not be possible depending on the use case, but immutable classes are guaranteed to be threadsafe, which is always a good thing.

Note that I could (and should) also use my constructor to validate that a `Person` is always created in a valid state:

```
class Person {
    private final String firstname;
    private final String lastname;
    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        if (firstname == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("a person must have a firstname");
        if (lastname == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("a person must have a lastname");
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getFirstname() { return firstname; }
    public String getLastname() { return lastname; }
}
```

*Additional note on immutability:*

Immutable objects are guaranteed to be threadsafe (always good), and have no chance to change when you do not expect it. This makes it easier to reason about immutable object. Less surprises.

That being said, trying to push for immutable objects all around tends to push you to split data and operations in different classes. It is easy to have immutable objects and "services" that operate on them. But if you go that way, you actually break one of the first principle of object oriented design: "encapsulate data and functions in a single component". Designing your classes to be immutable is a great idea, you just need to make sure you know where to stop.

Answer (score 0):

java beans = default constructor + getters + setters

now, let's say you want to model a person and in your model each person must have a name and surname. in java beans convention you would have to 1) create a person and then 2) populate it with name and surname. but in between 1) and 2) you have existing object that has inconsistent state, it;s a person without a name. in this trivial example it looks as a exaggeration but if you have a complex system it starts to matter.

regarding immutability: it's one of the the best ways to create readable and maintenable software. the less state and mutability, the better. if your object has to have setters then obviously it's not immutable. again it starts to matter in big complex systems, not a trivial hello world samples

Answer (score 0):

I'll start this post by reminding everyone that Java "beans" are a bit "different" from regular POJO classes. For e.g. they are usually created using reflection,  require a public no-arg constructor, have dumb getters/setters and so on.

Regarding the first part, let's assume you have a `Employee` Java bean with attributes like `name`, `age`, `gender` and so on. You also have code bits which:

1. Create the bean object
2. Set some attributes based on the passed in information

Let's say that no `name` was passed from the UI (assuming there is a binding between UI components and beans) when creating a Employee. The bean setter will be called with a `null` and this will be caught much later in your  code when actually *using* the Employee bean as opposed to when it was actually "set".

Regarding the second part, Java beans and mutable objects in general have to be very carefully used when writing multi-threaded code. If you "share" your objects across threads and consistently modify the fields instead of creating "new" ones, you are bound to run into objects which have "bad" state.

These sort of bugs are extremely difficult to trace given the possibility of other threads always seeing the correct state most of the time!